# Join two tables, select column based on value in first table

Tags: vb.net, linq

Imagine a table A with two columns "Type" and "Severity", and a table B with columns "Type", "Severity_1", "Severity_2", "Severity_3", "Severity_4".

A.Severity is an integer, and all the B.Severity_* fields contain a description.

I want to query table A for Type and Severity, and also return a third column with the corresponding description from table B.

Currently, I'm using LINQ and have a set of nested IF statements in the select clause. Is there a way to project table B or select out each {Type, Severity, Severity_*} record and union the results?

Comment: `"Severity_1", "Severity_2", ...` sounds like a bad db design; the result if which is usually  lots of If statements to undo the damage

Comment: Better design would be for table B to have columns "Type", "Severity" and "Description" and have one row for each severity.

Comment: @dwilliss It's another company's product, unfortunately I'm not in control of their DB design.

Comment: Just like Plutonix said, a bunch of If statements. Surely you can query each individual severity case (Where A.Severity = 1 etc.) four times, then concatenate the results? Bad design will result in headaches. Better yet, create a view which flattens everything on the SQL side, if you / they can.

Comment: Do the tables join on both `A.Type = B.Type` and `A.Severity = n : Severity_n` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should make a view, if possible, like this

```sql
select a.Type, a.Severity,
case a.Severity
when 1 then b1.Severity_1
when 2 then b2.Severity_2
when 3 then b3.Severity_3
when 4 then b4.Severity_4
end as Description
from TableA a
left join tableb b1 on a.Severity = 1 and a.Type = b1.Type
left join tableb b2 on a.Severity = 2 and a.Type = b2.Type
left join tableb b3 on a.Severity = 3 and a.Type = b3.Type
left join tableb b4 on a.Severity = 4 and a.Type = b4.Type
```

Then just query the view in Linq.